# Magento 2 how to make frontend customer logged activley for 5 days?

Tags: customer, login, session, customer-session

I have Magento 2.4.1. I want the to customer must be logged in for min 5 days once he logged in to my website.

I tried with PHP setting **session.gc_maxlifetime** but that not working.

Is there any solution that we can apply and make customers log in for 5 days?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Below Url:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/customer-online-options.html

```
Go to System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management and set Cookie Lifetime
```